# How to use jpeglib in xCode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, libjpeg

I'm developing an iPhone application and I'm kind of new to everything. I'm working on Mountain Lion OS X 10.8 and using xCode v4.5. I need JPEG handling capabilities in my project and I want to use the libjpeg (http://www.ijg.org/) library. I have tried a few different approaches, but being a bit naive, I'm not really sure how to begin. After downloading packages I've made usual ./configure; make and make install. Right now I have (jconfig.h, jerror.h, jmorecfg.h, jpeglib.h) under (/usr/local/include) and (libjpeg.a, libjpeg.la) under (/usr/local/lib) but I have no idea how to link/use this in my xCode project.
Can anyone link me to a tutorial or give me a push in the right direction?
If anyone successfully installed and used jpeg library please help..

Answer (score 3):

This is a bit of a pain, because you will need to compile LibJPEG for two architectures: ARM, for iOS, and x86, for the simulator.

1. Your best bet is to use `NSImage` or `CGImage`.  There already is a JPEG library on iOS, supplied with the system, so you don't need to use LibJPEG.
2. An alternative is to put the LibJPEG sources directly into your project (including the `*.c` files).  This way, they will be built correctly for different architectures (simulation and deployment).
3. You could also just build for ARM, and then forget about running the simulator.
4. Or you could build LibJPEG as a fat binary by compiling it twice and combining the resulting library (`libjpeg.a`) from each compilation with `libtool`.

   ```
   libtool -static path/to/arm/libjpeg.a path/to/x86/libjpeg.a -o libjpeg.a
   ```

You can see why the recommendation is to use `NSImage` or `CGImage`.  Better to use a library that is already installed rather than try to build and install a new one.

### How to make a fat static library

Since it sounds like you want to do things the hard way, here is an example of how to build a fat static library for i386 and ppc architectures.  This was done on a PowerPC OS X box, you will have to adjust if you want to compile for ARM and i386.

Note that you have to specify `--host` and `--build` for cross-compiling.  The values below are correct for my computer, but I am certain that they are wrong for your computer.

```
$ cd jpeg-8d
$ mkdir build-ppc build-i386
$ cd build-ppc
$ ../configure CFLAGS='-arch ppc -O2 -g' LDFLAGS='-arch ppc' \
        --enable-static --disable-shared
$ make -j2
$ cd ../build-i386
$  ../configure CFLAGS='-arch i386 -O2 -g' LDFLAGS='-arch i386' \
        --enable-static --disable-shared \
        --build=powerpc-apple-darwin9.8.0 --host=i386-apple-darwin9.8.0
$ make -j2
$ cd ..
$ file build-ppc/.libs/libjpeg.a 
build-ppc/.libs/libjpeg.a: current ar archive random library
$ file build-i386/.libs/libjpeg.a 
build-i386/.libs/libjpeg.a: current ar archive random library
$ libtool -static build-*/.libs/libjpeg.a -o libjpeg.a
$ file libjpeg.a
libjpeg.a: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
libjpeg.a (for architecture i386):      current ar archive random library
libjpeg.a (for architecture ppc):       current ar archive random library
```

Comment: My goal is to do DCT coefficient manipulation to hide some data in the JPEG image. I'm not sure if I can do that using just NSImage or CGImage. I need the library to work in both ARM and the simulator. I'm gonna try to copy the LibJPEG sources directly into my project because it looks like the easiest way to go but do I have to include the (libjpeg.a) as well? Also, based on the filelist.txt a few of the header files are generated during install (the jconfig.h and jmorecfg.h); what should I do about those?

Comment: The libjpeg.a file should not be copied because it is not source code, it is the compiled library.  Yes, you will need to copy jconfig.h and jmorecfg.h.

Comment: I tried copying the headers and source files directly into my project but I'm getting a lot of errors on the memory headers. I'm also not sure of I need to all other documents on the distribution (*.lo for example). May be it's better if I build libJPEG as a fat binary as you said. Could you please explain how to do that?

Comment: @Samar: Be warned that you are now doing things the hard way.  If you are not sure about what documents you need, this task might just be well beyond you.  I have updated the answer, but this is about as far as I am going.

Comment: @DietrichEpp : I have a similar problem. I am using a third party code which includes libjpeg source. It builds fine for the device, but gives "symbols not found for architecture i386" error for the simulator.

"_jpeg_gen_optimal_table referenced from _finish_pass_gather_phuff in jcphuff.o"

I saw that you mention that using the libjpeg source will build correctly for both the platforms but it does not seem to be doing so (now under build architectures, I have armv7 only, and this seems to work for the rest of my project so not sure what I am doing wrong)

Thanks.

Comment: @R.S: Have you tried building twice, once for i386 and once for armv7, like the example I provided?